# Как закомитить большой проект через git(GitHub)?

Tags: git, github, unreal-engine-4, unreal-engine-5, unreal-engine

Делаю проект на Unreal Engine который весит много гб. Сделал на ГитХабе репозиторий для проекта, подключил git lfs и сделал .gitignore для UE, но при попытке коммита выдаёт сообщшение что у меня слишком большие файлы, и нету возможности запушить.

**Вопрос:** Как вообще быть с репозиториями когда проект весит очень много? По словам знакомых, им удавалось заливать на репозитории проекты весом в 250гб+-, но я не могу понять как это они делают.

В инете читал на эти темы, ничего общего толком не нашёл. Кто может подсказать советом?

**P.S.** Кому интересно, .gitignore и git lfs файлы проекта:

```
# Visual Studio 2015 user specific files
.vs/

# Compiled Object files
*.slo
*.lo
*.o
*.obj

# Precompiled Headers
*.gch
*.pch

# Compiled Dynamic libraries
*.so
*.dylib
*.dll

# Fortran module files
*.mod

# Compiled Static libraries
*.lai
*.la
*.a
*.lib

# Executables
*.exe
*.out
*.app
*.ipa

# These project files can be generated by the engine
*.xcodeproj
*.xcworkspace
*.sln
*.suo
*.opensdf
*.sdf
*.VC.db
*.VC.opendb

# Precompiled Assets
SourceArt/**/*.png
SourceArt/**/*.tga

# Binary Files
Binaries/*
Plugins/*/Binaries/*

# Builds
Build/*

# Whitelist PakBlacklist-<BuildConfiguration>.txt files
!Build/*/
Build/*/**
!Build/*/PakBlacklist*.txt

# Don't ignore icon files in Build
!Build/**/*.ico

# Built data for maps
*_BuiltData.uasset

# Configuration files generated by the Editor
Saved/*

# Compiled source files for the engine to use
Intermediate/*
Plugins/*/Intermediate/*

# Cache files for the editor to use
DerivedDataCache/*
```

.gitattribures:

```
# Auto detect text files and perform LF normalization
* text=auto
Content/** filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
.uasset filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
.umap filter=lfs diff=lfs merge=lfs -text
```

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/working-with-files/managing-large-files/about-large-files-on-github

Comment: Увы, эту документацию я читал. Ничего о моей проблеме там написано не было. Даже Git LFS не справляется с размером.

Comment: Ну по ссылке написано, что репозитории больше 5 Гб могут блокироваться. Может и не имеет смысл грузить на Github, если "весит много гб"? Откуда у вас вообще такие конские размеры, может забыли какие-то временные файлы игнорировать?

Comment: Проект на Unreal-е. Всякие текстуры, меши, карты, ассеты и т.д могут занимать достаточно много места. Здесь у меня стоит вопрос о том, возможно ли это вообще сделать? Проекты я делаю для своего портфолио. Если на гитхаб места нехватает, как лучше проекты хранить? Просто запаковывать в архив и кидать работодателю, или как?

Comment: В гите имеет смысл хранить код (текст), а бинарные ассеты - отдельно, например на фтп или специальных органайзерах для ассетов. Кроме того, один джамбо проект - не есть хорошо. Имеет смысл делить не несколько. Ну а для портфолио проект должен быть как можно меньше, вряд ли кому захочется возиться с многогигабайтным бегемотом.

Comment: Дубликат? [Не могу отправить большие файлы в GitHub](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1549113/1365)

Comment: Гит создан для текстовых файлов, а не для текстур, карт и прочих ресурсов. Правильный ответ на ваш вопрос - никак. Гит не для этого.