# Не могу отправить большие файлы в GitHub

Tags: unity3d, git, github

Добавил набор текстур в игру, при push выходит ошибка

```
remote: error: File Assets/Textures/BackGround/BG/cyberpunk-overlay-effects-for-platformer-game/PSD/1-30.psd is 240.80 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large
```

Хотя я скачал gitLfs и написал все команды

> git lfs install
>
> git lfs track "*.psd"
>
> git add .gitattributes
>
> git commit -m "Add design file"

Comment: Пара текстур?... Каждая по сто мигов?

Comment: Неправильно описал, набор текстур

Comment: Ну так закидывайте их отдельно. Не в одном же они файле.

Comment: Так у меня потом в иерархии бардак будет, разве нельзя как-то решить эту проблему через git?

Comment: Как вариант, просто сделай папку и в ней уже все текстуры, вряд ли получится закинуть большой размер.

Comment: Очень сомневаюсь. Проще разобрать бардак, чем ломать голову над неразрешимыми вопросами.

Comment: 1. по поводу программы git. это программа для отслеживания изменения в исходных текстах программ. для хранения блобов она разработчиками не предназначалась ни раньше ни теперь. 2. программа git всего лишь сообщает вам, что удалённая сторона (сервер github) не приняла ваши огромные блобы. и предложила (сторона, а не программа git) воспользоваться своим отдельным сервисом github-lfs.

Comment: Юнити у вас прямо из файлов фотошопа текстуры берет?